# Giving number format in Excel through C#

Tags: c#, html, styles, export-to-excel, number-formatting

I am trying to export to Excel from a `GridView`.

Below is my code:

```
 public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
        {

            HttpContext curContext = HttpContext.Current;
            curContext.Response.Clear();

            curContext.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=" + fileName);
            curContext.Response.Charset = "";
            curContext.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
            curContext.Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
            StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
            HtmlTextWriter htw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
            htw.WriteLine("<font size=6>COMPANY<font>");
            htw.WriteLine("</br>");
            ExcelGridView.HeaderStyle.BackColor = Color.Orange;
            ExcelGridView.RenderControl(htw);
            ExcelGridView.Rows[2].
            htw.WriteLine("<table border=1 bgcolor=#DBA901>");
            htw.WriteLine("<tr >");
            htw.WriteLine("<td>");
            htw.WriteLine("Total");
            htw.WriteLine("</td>");
            htw.WriteLine("<td colspan=1>");
            htw.WriteLine(totalQ);
            htw.WriteLine("</td>");
            htw.WriteLine("<td>");
            htw.WriteLine("</td>");
            htw.WriteLine("<td  style=mso-number-format:.00>");
            htw.WriteLine(totalP);
            htw.WriteLine("</td>");
            htw.WriteLine("</tr>");
            htw.WriteLine("<table>");

            byte[] byteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(sw.ToString());
            MemoryStream s = new MemoryStream(byteArray);
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(s, Encoding.ASCII);
            curContext.Response.Write(sr.ReadToEnd());

            curContext.Response.End();
        }
```

My problem is that in the table which is generated in Excel the numbers are not shown in decimal format.

**For example 123.45 will show as it is, but 123.00 will show as 123. I want to enforce .00 in those values.  Also I want to enforce it only in the third and fourth column only.**

The values in the GridView are as I want them to be but while exporting to Excel only the above problem is happening.

Can anyone suggest me a possible solution? Thank you.

**Note**: in the above code **ExcelGridView.RenderControl(htw);** is the code for GridView and **ExcelGridView** is the name of the GridView.

Comment: I tried your code, but used StringBuilder instead HtmlTextWriter and decimal format looks good.

Comment: are you getting the decimal values as 123.00 instead of 123 if you use stringbuilder? Also the values i am passing are in decimal format.Also i have heard that excel 2010 has formatting issues with decimals.Is it true?

Comment: If I pass 123 I got 123.00 in Excel. If I pass 123.1 I got 123.10 in Excel. Can you try?

Comment: hi if i am using your code i am getting blank excel.Do you think it might be because of ExcelGridView.RenderControl(htw); line? because its the main line for passing gridview into excel.

Answer (score 2):

Try EPPlus library for creating Excel from C#:

http://epplus.codeplex.com/

With this library, you can set cell format as number, with decimal ans thousand separators.

Try to use StringBuilder (custom format works):

```
public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
{

    HttpContext curContext = HttpContext.Current;
    curContext.Response.Clear();
    curContext.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=" + fileName);
    curContext.Response.Charset = "";
    curContext.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
    curContext.Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.Append("<font size=6>COMPANY<font>");
    sb.Append("</br>");
    ExcelGridView.HeaderStyle.BackColor = Color.Orange;
    ExcelGridView.RenderControl(htw);
    ExcelGridView.Rows[2].
    sb.Append("<table border=1 bgcolor=#DBA901>");
    sb.Append("<tr >");
    sb.Append("<td>");
    sb.Append("Total");
    sb.Append("</td>");
    sb.Append("<td colspan=1>");
    sb.Append(totalQ);
    sb.Append("</td>");
    sb.Append("<td>");
    sb.Append("</td>");
    sb.Append("<td  style=mso-number-format:.00>");
    sb.Append(totalP);
    sb.Append("</td>");
    sb.Append("</tr>");
    sb.Append("<table>");

    byte[] byteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(sb.ToString());
    MemoryStream s = new MemoryStream(byteArray);
    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(s, Encoding.ASCII);
    curContext.Response.Write(sr.ReadToEnd());

    curContext.Response.End();
}
```

Comment: does that library require interop (to have excel installed on the server)?

Comment: no.we are not using interop or openxml as we faced problems with them while hosting on our server.Its just simple gridview to excel

Comment: @Danilo hi we had considered your solution before but our supervisors don't want us to use any third party tools.

Comment: @JPHellemons No, EPPlus does not require Excel. It works by writing .xlsx files, which is an open format.

Comment: @nitinvertigo tell your supervisors that it is open source and under GNU LGPL http://epplus.codeplex.com/license license and that it saves you a lot of time and effort.

Comment: @JPHellemons Hi i have talked to our supervisors and they are keeping it as last option.Isn't there something we can do with this code?Because if we change to EPPlus many more changes have to be made.and also adding the required dll for epplus may not function on our server.thats why we dint use openxml.

Comment: If it is a licensing issue, I have used Carlos Excel Writer to generate Excel files http://www.carlosag.net/tools/excelxmlwriter/ it's free. or try: `sb.Append("<td  style=\"mso-number-format:.00\">");`

Comment: @JPHellemons actually its not a licensing issue.Whenever we try to add third party reference to our server, it crashes.so we are trying to avoid adding any third party dlls.

Comment: @nitinvertigo, you mean that the application pool in iis restarts? or that the whole windows server goes down? what is in the eventlog then? seems to me that fixing the server crashing will help you more in the future, because you can benefit more from nuget packages etc. that server crashing thing should be posted on serverfault

Comment: @JPHellemons, i meant that the server stops responding.Anyhow we are completely abandoning this idea and moving on to other project.Thanks for all your help.